# How do I make my pet pick up items?

Tags: torchlight

When I started the game, I'm sure I saw a tutorial tip that I could have my pet pickup items directly into their inventory, but I cannot remember how to do that.

How do I click an item on the floor to have my pet pick it up? Right now, I am picking up the junk and then have to move it from my inventory to that of my pet and I'm just too lazy for that. :)

Comment: i think it's the CTRL key which happens to also be the same key you use to not move if your attacking (perfect for ranged weapons) but i don't recall myself. i generally give stuff to my Pet manually because i use him to sell the crap i have in my inventory

Comment: @Memor-X - Unfortunately, that is not working for me (it seems the CTRL key has no effect so Ctrl-Click just sends me running to that location).

Comment: That last part should be an answer, rather than part of the question, to make a clearer Q&A for future people who have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Torchlight manual PDF found in the game's installation folder, holding `Shift` and clicking the Left Mouse Button will send your pet to collect the dropped item.